# Why doesn't Visual Studio (or Resharper) warn for out of range errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When I enter this code:

```
int[] test = new int[5];
test[5] = 7;
```

Visual Studio, nor Resharper warns me about the error. It seems to be this is pretty easy to detect? And a common mistake...

Maybe it's in some situations too complex to detect this, but in some situations it seems pretty straight forward. So, is there a specific reason why this doesn't generate a compiler or Resharper warning?

Comment: This is opinion based unless not a resharper developer answers. Also, even if it's easy to see for you it might be incredible difficult to see for a compiler or code review tool. I guess it's benefit doesn't outweight the implementation costs.

Comment: in my opinion it's really not worth it to have this feature as it is a very simple, easily detectable mistake.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: at runtime this is easily detectable indeed, because you get an exception. But some applications are hard to test, so all possible errors detected before compiling are big time savers.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot about `Array.Resize` function.

What if developer called that function at runtime and then use with higher index.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Initialize array for example.
    char[] array = new char[4];
    array[0] = 'p';
    array[1] = 'e';
    array[2] = 'r';
    array[3] = 'l';

    // Display the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Resize the array from 4 to 6 elements.
    Array.Resize(ref array, 6);

    // Display the array that has been resized.
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it's not always that easy. But for example Resharper could add a warning. Developer can then check for himself if it's indeed wrong or not. In most cases it will be an error made by the developer. Like Resharper warns you if you compare references with each other without Equals. It's not always wrong. It's just often wrong, so it warns you about it.